# How to write an XML MessageBodyWriter provider with jersey

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am not trying to solve any problem in particular, but rather I am on a learning path to jersey.

I have an entity class marked like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myentity")
@XmlRootElement
public class MyEntity implements serializable {
  // lots of methods...
}
```

and the corresponding jersey service

```
@Stateless
@Path("entity")
public class EntityFacade {

    @GET
    @Path("{param}")
    @Produces({"application/xml;charset=UTF-8"})
    public List<MyEntity> find(@PathParam("param") String param) {
       List entities = entityManager.getResultList(); // retrieve list from db
       return entities;
    }

}
```

Which give a correct XML response.
Supposing I want to write a MessageBodyWriter which replicate same behavior, which is producing an XML response, how could I do that ?

```
@Provider
public class TrasformerMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Object> {

    @Override
    public long getSize(Object o, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // return true or false depending if I want to rewrite the response
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object o, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
            OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException {
        // what do I need to write here...
    }
}
```

by marking with @Provider annotation I can see the message body writer is correctly invoked.

When writeTo is invoked, Object o is a Vector and Type genericType is a List but at this point I am completely lost on how I could transform the object in XML.

Last, if everything is already provided by jersey and its annotations, how can a MessageBodyWriter be useful ?

Again, I am repeating that this is just an academic exercise.

Comment: You may find the following post helpful as an example of implementing a `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter`: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typically one would use a `MessageBodyWriter` to convert objects to data formats that Jersey knows nothing about. Here's an example of translating a `TableData` domain object to CSV:

```java
@Singleton
@Produces("text/csv")
@Provider
public class FederationCsvWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<TableData> {

  @Override
  public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return TableData.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
  }

  @Override
  public long getSize(TableData data, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation annotations[], MediaType mediaType) {
    return -1;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeTo(TableData data, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
      MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    Writer osWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(osWriter, ',', '"', "\r\n");
    if (data.getResultCount() > 0) {
      //Write the header
      writer.writeNext(data.getResult().get(0).keySet().toArray(new String[data.getResult().get(0).keySet().size()]));

      //Write the data
      for (ModelData row: data.getResult()) {
        writer.writeNext(row.values().toArray(new String[row.values().size()]));
      }
    }
    writer.flush();
  }

}
```

In your example you could either create XML by inspecting the object yourself and feeding the result to the `OutputStream` or your could use JAXB (which Jersey uses internally) to marshall the objects directly to the `OutputStream`. For the purposes of your exercise JAXB is probably more interesting.

Comment: Using JAXB Unless I write a wrapper class, the List is returned by the web service as a Vector<MyEntity> therefore I cannot marshall it.

Comment: Can you explain that getSize should return -1 ?

Comment: @StonyZhang - From the javadoc ( http://goo.gl/XyrGV ): `Called before writeTo to ascertain the length in bytes of the serialized form of t. A non-negative return value is used in a HTTP Content-Length header.`

Comment: According to the spec you're not supposed to close the OutputStream. Will closing the writer not close the OutputStream too?

Comment: The -1 return value for getSize() is due to changes in JAX-RS and getSize() has been deprecated. `As of JAX-RS 2.0, the method has been deprecated and the value returned by the method is ignored by a JAX-RS runtime. All MessageBodyWriter implementations are advised to return -1 from the method. Responsibility to compute the actual Content-Length header value has been delegated to JAX-RS runtime.` Here is a new [link to the above reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) by @condit.