# Implementing Hypermedia in RESTful JAX-RS Apache CXF

Tags: rest, cxf, jax-rs

I am working in a RESTful application developed in Apache CXF and I would like to introduce hypermedia functionality to it.

Most of our jaxrs:serviceBeans follow this template:

```
@GET
@Path("/{exampleId}")
public ExampleJSON get(@PathParam("exampleId") Integer exampleId) {
    ExampleJSON example;
    // Load data from repository here...

    // Add link to self.
    String href = javax.ws.rs.core.Link.fromResource(ExampleService.class).build().getUri().toString();

    // HypermediaLink is a custom object to hold a "href" and "rel" strings
    HypermediaLink linkToSelf = new HypermediaLink();
    linkToSelf.setHref(href + example.getId());
    linkToSelf.setRel("self");

    // Inherited method, just adds a HypermediaLink to a collection in the parent class
    example.addHypermediaLink(linkToSelf);

    // Return JSON compatible object, JACKSON will serialize it nicely.
    return example;
}
```

This is the basic concept. Keep in mind that I simplified this code for explanation purposes; so, it can be easily understood.

This code works fine; but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this with Apache CXF. I have some ideas for how to enhancing it; however, it will require some custom annotations.

I see some examples using Jersey, but I would like to stick with Apache CXF.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am thinking whether to vote to close your question: what is your actual problem? What problem do you want to solve? You should not ask for recommendations here.

Comment: @AndreiI, current approach is very verbose. I am looking for a library to do such thing better. Spring WS has something like this https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/ . Right now, I am trying to do something similar in Apache CXF.

Comment: CXF doesn't appear to have any extra features. [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/declarative-linking.html) and [Resteasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/LinkHeader.html#d0e543) both have declarative ways of handling links (which are implementation specific). Looking at the [CXF docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html), I can't spot anything similar. Annotation/combined with under the hood filters and interceptors are what's used with Jersey and Resteasy. So you may need to create your own implementation of such a feature.

Comment: Here's an [implementation](https://code.google.com/p/jax-rs-hateoas/) I found with a quick google search. You may be able to gain something from it

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet, I have seen this before. The only issue with it is that *jax-rs-hateoas-core* returns a Response while I return a POJO (ExampleJSON) which is later serialized by Jackson.

Comment: Regardless if you return your pojo, or wrap your pojo in a Response, the JSON will only be your pojo representation. It's just a matter of preference what you want your method signature to be. Personally, I tend to always return a Response.

Comment: Did you try CXF interceptors? Call the Spring Link provider with an outinterceptor that add your provided links to the message.

Answer (score 1):

I would leverage some features of JAX-RS and / or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) to implement the link adding under the hood at the serialization level. So you wouldn't need to have a specific field for the link within the bean itself.

- You could implement a custom `MessageBodyWriter` to generate a different JSON payload (for example) for your POJOs than the default. So you could dynamically add the link.

  See this answer for more details: [How to write an XML MessageBodyWriter provider with jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741853/how-to-write-an-xml-messagebodywriter-provider-with-jersey).
- If you use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) for the serialization, you could implement a custom serializer. Note that this is generic and will work for all supported format of Jackson.

  Below is a sample code:

  ```
  public class LinkBeanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SomeBean> {
      @Override
      public void serialize(SomeBean bean, JsonGenerator jgen,
              SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
                    JsonProcessingException {
          jgen.writeStartObject();

          // Fields
          jgen.writeNumberField("id", bean.getId());
          // Things could be generic using reflection

          // Link
          String href = javax.ws.rs.core.Link.fromResource(SomeBean.class).build().getUri().toString();
          HypermediaLink linkToSelf = new HypermediaLink();
          linkToSelf.setHref(href + bean.getId());
          linkToSelf.setRel("self");
          jgen.writeObjectField("hypermediaLink", linkToSelf);

          jgen.writeEndObject();
      }
  }
  ```

  Note that we could make this serializer more generic I think (something like `extends JsonSerializer<Object>`)

  See this answer for more details: [Processing JSON response using JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753109/processing-json-response-using-jax-rs) (how to register the custom serializer within JAX-RS, ...).
- Perhaps implementing a `WriterInterceptor` could solve your problem but there is impact on the beans  since you need to have field hypermediaLink. The interceptor could be responsible of filling the field.

  See this answer for more details: [Jersey Update Entity Property MessageBodyWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679429/jersey-update-entity-property-messagebodywriter).

IMO the more convenient solution is the second one. It's transparent and support all the formats supported by Jackson.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry