# Jersey Update Entity Property MessageBodyWriter

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I want to create a Jersey provider ([MessageBodyWriter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e6723)) that update a dto object property and continue the chain to Jersey-json default provider an return the json object. **the problem**  is that looks like default provider is not called so the output of my rest service become empty as soon as I register the new Provider.

```
@Provider
public class TestProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<MyDTO>
{
    @Override
    public long getSize(
        MyDTO arg0, Class<?> arg1, Type arg2, Annotation[] arg3, MediaType arg4)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> clazz, Type type, Annotation[] arg2, MediaType arg3)
    {
        return type == MyDTO.class;
    }


    @Override
    public void writeTo(
        MyDTO dto,
        Class<?> paramClass,
        Type paramType, Annotation[] paramArrayOfAnnotation,
        MediaType mt,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> paramMultivaluedMap,
        OutputStream entityStream) //NOPMD
    throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
        dto.setDescription("text Description");
        // CONTINUE THE DEFAULT SERIALIZATION PROCESS
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MessageBodyWriter` shouldn't need to perform an logic to manipulate entities. It's responsibility is simply to marshal/serialize.

What you are looking for instead is an [`WriterIntercptor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html), whose purpose is to do exactly what you are trying to do, manipulate the entity before being serialized.

It's all explained [here in the Jersey Doc for Inteceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9678).

Here's an example

```
@Provider
public class MyDTOWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        Object entity = context.getEntity();
        if (entity instanceof MyDTO) {
            ((MyDTO)entity).setDescription("Some Description");
        }
        context.proceed();
    }  
}
```

You can add annotation so only certain resource methods/classes use this interceptor, e.g.

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;

@NameBinding
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AddDescription {

}
...

@AddDescription
@Provider
public class MyDTOWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {
...

@Path("dto")
public class MyDTOResource {

    @GET
    @AddDescription
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getDto() {
        return Response.ok(new MyDTO()).build();
    }
}
```

If for some reason you can't alter the class (maybe that's why you need to set the description here, who's knows), then you can use [Dynamic Binding](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9921), where you don't need to to use annotations. You can simple do some reflection to check the method or class. The link has an example.