# Processing JSON response using JAX-RS

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jax-rs

```
I have a json payload like this:

{
   "account":    {

      "sample_id": 1424876658095,
      "parameters":       [
                  {
            "name": "email",
            "value": "hello@xyz.com"
         },
                  {
            "name": "first_name",
            "value": "FIRSTNAME"
         },
                  {
            "name": "last_name",
            "value": "LASTNAME"
         }
      ]
   },
   "assests": [   {

      "tran_id": "1234567",

   }]
}
```

The above json payload is getting generated in the response of a rest API call.
I would like to process this response in java to generate something like this:

```
{
   "account":    {

      "sample_id": 1424876658095,
      "email_id": "hello@xyz.com",
      "first_name": "FIRSTNAME",
      "last_name": "LASTNAME",
   },
   "assets": [   {

      "tran_id": "1234567",

   }]
}
```

I am using the JAX-RS specification for the REST API, but I am not able to find any library to process the response.

Comment: Where do you want to process this response? On the server side before sending it back to the client? Do you have the hand on the RESTful service?

Comment: yes on the server side.Yes , I developed the restful service.

Comment: So this means that you return a bean with other inner beans with the structure described by the first code snippet and you want that this object graph to be serialized to the second format? Which technology fo you use for serrialization? Jackson?

Comment: yes i am using jackson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to leverage the Jackson serialization within JAX-Rs, you need to implement as custom serializer.

There are two steps to do that:

- **Create the custom serializer**

  Here is a sample of a custom Jackson serializer for your needs based on beans `AccountBean` and `ParameterBean`:

  ```
  public class AccountBeanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<AccountBean> {
      @Override
      public void serialize(AccountBean accountBean, JsonGenerator jgen,
              SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
              JsonProcessingException {
          jgen.writeStartObject();
          jgen.writeNumberField("sample_id", accountBean.getSampleId());
          List<ParameterBean> parameters = accountBean.getParameters();
          for (ParameterBean parameterBean : parameters) {
              jgen.writeStringField(parameterBean.getName(),
                      parameterBean.getValue());
          }
          jgen.writeEndObject();
      }
  }
  ```

  I assume the class for your response if something like that:

  ```
  class ResponseBean
      field account = class AccountBean
         field sampleId (long)
         field parameters = class ParameterBean
      (...)
  ```
- **Register the custom serializer**

  You need then to provide a custom Jackson configuration within a context resolver. For this, you can create an implementation of the interface `ContextResolver` annotated with `Provider`.

  ```
  @Provider
  public class CustomJacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
      private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

      public JacksonConfig() {
          this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
          SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
          module.addSerializer(AccountBean.class, new AccountSerializer());
          this.objectMapper.registerModule(module);
      }

      public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
          return objectMapper;
      }
  }
  ```

Following links could help you:

- http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization
- https://books.google.fr/books?id=cFBptKRXrk4C&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=jaxrs+ContextResolver&source=bl&ots=FlOzDeookf&sig=iY0dM8l5A0svwxB-hsfFO94eIqc&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=B5vwVKSmO8bbat2BguAB&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=jaxrs%20ContextResolver&f=false
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider

Hope this helps,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement a custom `MessageBodyWriter` for this to generate a different JSON payload for your POJOs than the default.

Comment: Thanks! Let me explore this.